# Return correct data for a given date.

Tags: sql-server-2008

All,

I have two table one call Employee and the other table call Target Ratio. They are related via FK EmployeeID

```
tblEmployee
EmployeeID FirstName LastName
1              John     Doe

tblTargetRatio
TargetRatioID EmployeeID EffectiveDate Ratio
      1            1        1/1/2012     8
      2            1        6/1/2012     5
      3            1        9/1/2012     7
```

My question is how can I query tblTargetRatio table to return correct record for the following cases:

```
1 EmployeeID = 1 and Date = 03/12/2012 (Expecting Ratio = 8)
2 EmployeeID = 1 and Date = 10/10/2012 (Expecting Ratio = 7)
3 EmployeeID = 1 and Date = 08/12/2012 (Expecting Ratio = 5)
```

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are looking for the most recent effective date.  You can do this by looking for the max value less than the value being searched (where `@Date` is the date being searched):

```
select top 1 * from tblTargetRatio
where employeeid = 1 and effectivedate < @Date
order by effectivedate desc
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6d4b/2

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't realize it was that simple.